# Find out who modified a TraceFlag

Tags: debugging, traceflag, event-monitoring

We have a team structure where dozens of developers share one sandbox. A lot of corporate machinery is involved, but we are working on splitting out development into a greater number of environments. However, that could still take a while, and every day that I need to debug something, we get the lovely error message that our daily limit of debug logs is over 1000MB, and I have to go in and delete ~100 `ApexLog` records just to change my own log levels.

I asked our entire dev team if they were okay with us lowering the default settings (`SFDC_DevConsole`) to `NONE` everywhere, then asking people to use different trace flags if they actually need more granularity. Everyone signed off on the change, I made it, then the next morning, the `ApexCode` level was right back to `FINEST`. It has happened a few times.

I tried to dig into who keeps reverting my change, so I can broaden the conversation. But these changes do not show up in the `Setup Audit Trail`. We have Event Monitoring in this org, so I have some tools to dig deeper, but I do not know how to use them.

**Is there a way to find out who modified a `TraceFlag`?**

Comment: Have you tried contacting salesforce support? I really doubt such a feature would be available as it depends on the maturity level of the team, rather than having to micro-manage who updates the trace flag! I agree it's troublesome, but can't have that much freedom on multi-tenant platforms

Comment: should no other answer emerge, one could imagine a custom chrome extension that monitored the UI and sent an alert

Answer (score 2):

Poor man's monitoring solution - use the Tooling API and poll changes to TraceFlag. One option is to use something like https://github.com/neowit/tooling-force.com and wrap a simple shell script around it that calls the API at whatever frequency. You could also pull a list of currently logged-in users at the same time and then play a game of Clue to see if you can find your Col. Mustard with the candlestick in a conservatory.

Comment: +1 for `Clue` and `candlestick`